# It is possible hide Hotels And Restaurants? (on locally stored OpenStreetMap maps)

Tags: openstreetmap

I'm extracting Maps to use them on my Android app's locally, without internet connexion on the phones. I extract the small maps of cities areas, for example, barcelona city area, with OSMCONVERT.

The problem is that the maps have commercial poi's shown on the map, like for example hotels or restaurants.

How can i remove/hide them from my locally stored maps?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "extracting" you mean you have downloaded Web map tiles, then the answer is no, you can't hide them since they are drawn into the bitmaps. You will need to [render your own tiles](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Creating_your_own_tiles).

Comment: how can i do it?, i can't find the way with your link